# How to make an expect statement be condition for if statement

Tags: protractor

I'm currently finding the current url with

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("example.com");
```

I want to make it into an if statement that would the url as the condition. How could I do that?

```
if(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().toEqual("example.com") == "example.com"){
//do stuff
}
```

This is what I tried and it did not work

Answer (score 2):

`getCurrentUrl()` is a promise, so you need to resolve it yourself to use the value as a conditional.

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url) => {
    if(~url.indexOf('example.com')) {
        // code
    }
    else {
        // code
    }
})
```

Finally, Jasmine methods like `toEqual` should be used strictly with test assertions.  I wouldn't use them outside of an `expect` statement like you have above.